# Process that starts 1 week before a date

Tags: scheduled-apex, datetime, process-builder

I need to make a process that sends out a chatter notification 1 week before a date on an account.

I only see options to run the process when a record is created or edited. How can I make it run when it is 1 week before the set date?

Comment: Not sure what exactly your use-case is, but you can create a new date field and using a workflow rule update it to your (specific date - 1 week) on every create and update. Then you can have a time-dependent workflow fire off this date field.

Comment: If a form is not filled out on an account I need to notify that owner that the fields need to be filled out 1 week before the due date. @AAU

Comment: ok 2 corrections, we do not need a second date field in case we had to write a time dependent action and also I did not read properly that you need to send out a chatter notification. Please ignore my previous comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked too much on Process Builder as yet, but I think the following should satisfy what you are looking for.

1. On the node where you select the object, you can select when a
   record is created or edited.
2. On the node where you define the criteria, define the criteria for
   the fields that need to be filled in but are not. On the same node,
   there is a section called "`Advanced`", under that you have a checkbox
   called "`Do you want to execute the actions only when specified
   changes are made to the record?`".
   Once you select that, you
   should see a node for "`Scheduled Actions`".
3. On the Scheduled Action node, you can define the schedule as `7 Days
   before Due Date` and also define the Chatter Post action.

Comment: The scheduled actions will only be scheduled once the record is created or edited. I do not want this. I want it to happen even if its not edited. It should happen when it is a week before the set date.

Comment: Do you mean you need to handle the Accounts that are already created in the system and might not get updated before the due date? In that case, I think the only option is to write a `Scheduled Apex` that runs once per day and picks up all Accounts that have due date 7 days after the current date.